# How to prevent auto-backup of an Android app?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, android-jobscheduler

I face very weird situation on certain device (Nexus 5x with Android 7): when I clean its data and uninstall it, then install it with Studio, the app is not unitialized but it uses data from 24th january! I tried the same procedure with a tablet and the app has no data.

I have repeated this procedure many times, I cleaned my project, rebuilt it multiple times and it always starts with 24th january data (both database and shared prefs).

I even tried adb shell and run as to clean up data:

```
bullhead:/data/data/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug $ ls -l databases/
total 232
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a259 u0_a259 98304 2017-02-05 11:03 lelimath.sqlite
-rw------- 1 u0_a259 u0_a259 16928 2017-02-05 11:03 lelimath.sqlite-journal
```

I deleted them and the app seemed empty - until I deleted it and installed again - 24th january was back.

This is a log how it starts:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug/lelisoft.com.lelimath.activities.DashboardActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug | lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug.test
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug, real application class is lelisoft.com.lelimath.helpers.LeliMathApp.
D/l.c.l.h.LeliMathApp: onCreate()
D/l.c.l.h.BalanceHelper: Current points balance: 234
```

This is a location of a database, got from a debugger:

```
/data/user/0/lelisoft.com.lelimath.debug/databases/lelimath.sqlite
```

Gradle:

```
android {
signingConfigs {
}
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "lelisoft.com.lelimath"
    resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'LeliMath'
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 300
    versionName '3.0.0'
    resValue "string", "app_build_number", getDate();
    resValue "string", "app_version", versionName;
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        resValue 'string', 'app_name', 'LeliMath DEV'
    }
}
```

Manifest portion:

```
<application
    android:name=".helpers.LeliMathApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

I do not want o factory reset my phone to get rid off this data. I do not think that this data is in my build. I have not added them and the app in the tablet was empty when installed.

Comment: Can you be specific what previous data do you get?

Comment: Database and shared preferences. I can see that there is no ormlite initialization.

Comment: And only on devices from API 23 + right ?

Comment: Does this issue occur any device below marshmallow?

Comment: I just ran emulator for a tablet with SDK 18 and it worked as expected. Upgrade kept device previous data, fresh install (after app removal) had no data at all. Then I started emulator for another tablet with SDK 23 and it had no data. It really seems that the problem is local to my phone.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Can you post your manifest as well. To confirm the issue :)

Comment: Added app section. Do you mean backup attributes? Strange is that I had several modifications so why concrete date is kept?

Comment: hmm, I ll answer the cause of it!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since Android 6.0 (v 23) onward, Android introduced a new feature called [Auto-backup for apps](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html) . What this does is, it performs a  backup of certain files of an application to a user's Google drive. The list of files it updates include:

- Shared preferences files
- Files in the directory returned by `getFilesDir()`
- Files in the directory returned by `getDatabasePath(String)`
- Files in directories created with `getDir(String, int)`
- Files on external storage in the directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir(String)`

Now this line in the `manifest.xml` is responsible for it :

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

If you prefer to disable the backup, should you choose to set the value to `false`.

Furthermore, the data backed up is in a 24 hour interval and Android uses the [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html) API for this purpose, so which means a user has no control over the process of data being transferred.

Also, the space for auto-backups is limited to `25`MB , and which is not counted against the user's space quota.

Also, you can set to `<include>` and `<exclude>` certain type of data being uploaded, for instance you may not need to save a user confidential data, so it is flexible for that as well, more info on that is available at : [Android Auto Backup for Apps (100 Days of Google Dev)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXacyy0HSW0)

Comment: Great. I can see the app in Manage backups in the Drive but I cannot delete it. Can I configure Manifest via gradle that this property is off for debug release?

Comment: Confirmed, setting to false helped. I tried to put resValue 'string', 'full_backup', 'false' in gradle and reference it within manifest: android:fullBackupContent="@string/full_backup, but this did not work and backup was loaded anyway.

Comment: I did not understand it complete. Trying to disable backup while on debug builds?

Comment: Exactly. I want a production build be backed up, but debug build not.

Comment: Why not set `android:allowBackup="false"` and set it to true, before building the release apk ?

Comment: Not very elegant and it is easy to commit it accidentally or forget to change it before build.

Comment: Hmm, then in that case you should ask a new question with that specific problem I believe. I have not been to that specific problem. :/ regrets :/

Comment: One inaccuracy about size limit of backup: 25MB for each application per one user/device. It means if user has 2 devices, then limit will be 25MB for each user's app per device.

Comment: How do i let my app users decide, if they want to enable backup or not? Why is the preference of backup or not to backup done at compile time? Why doesnt google gives an option to let this be decided by the user of the app. What i am asking is let the dev decide what to backup and what to not backup, so that the app behaves as intended., BUT let the user of the app decide if this backup even happens or not.

Comment: Is it possible to clear/remove (not disable) the backup in any way? We are having some problems because of it specific to the beta testing process.

Answer (score 9):

```
<application ...
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:fullBackupContent="false"
    tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
</application>
```

Comment: What's the tools:replace for?

Comment: tools:replace is used to override the AndroidManifest settings. Let's say if any library you are using has the android:allowBackup="true" it'll override the value.

Answer (score 7):

Simply change

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

to

```
android:allowBackup="false"
```

And if you are using any dependency, to override this property use

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup"
android:allowBackup="false"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and really had to scratch my head because Google has not highlighted a subtle change in App backup feature.Starting from API level 23, all app data will be automatically backed up in Google drive. This data would be restored back when the app is installed back. So the data does not go away even when you uninstall the app.

Mostly your app manifest would have an entry like this -

```
android:allowBackup="true"
```

Change the value to `false` or else follow the below link and configure an xml letting the backup service know what to backup and what not to.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup.html

Answer (score 0):

i know this is not a perfect solution but its worked for me.

after uninstalling the specific app i switch off the device and switch on the device, Device OS not calling backup check from cloud

Answer (score 0):

One way to clear the backup of the app is:

**Clear that app data and its cache.**

**Note:** This is a temporary solution as uninstalling and reinstalling the app would restore the backup automatically.